# Sharepoint and Database interaction, what should I do?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sharepoint

I've developped a MySQL database containing informations about different documents and products. Now I have to create a user interface which has to be integrated in a sharepoint. As I'm new to sharepoint, I am a bit lost and I don't know what I should choose (developping a Web Application on visual studio which will be hosted on Sharepoint, developping a WebPart...etc I have no idea of what to do).

So my question is : What's the best option to develop this user interface on Sharepoint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go different ways:

1. Push data from your MySQL database to SharePoint list periodically or event-based.
   In this case you already have UI interface of SharePoint list view. If out-of-box UI not enough then you can create your own using javascript or by creating your own web part or by creating SharePoint add-in.
   You can do it many ways:
   1.1. C# console app (create with Visual Studio). Console app will connect to your SQL database and create list items in SharePoint list. You can schedule this console in Windows Task Scheduler.
   1.2. Another periodically running code that external to your database. May be PowerShell script, SharePoint timerjob, Windows service, SharePoint workflow or something else. This code will connect to database and push data to SharePoint list.
   1.3. I don't know how you fill your database but in your logic you can add logic to also create SharePoint list item in list when you add record to database.
   It is event-based logic.
2. Get all data from your database in SharePoint on page load each time. 
   Add some web part to SharePoint that get data from your database on page load (you can mix some parts below to get intented behavior):
   2.1. Create your own Visual Web Part in Visual Studio. Deploy solution with web part to SharePoint. Add web part to any page in SharePoint.
   This web part will get data from your database on page load.
   2.2. You can create web service hosted anywhere (SharePoint, another place) that return data from your database.
   Create javascript logic that call this web service to get data and render data.
   Add this javascript logic in Content Editor or Script Editor web part in SharePoint. CE and SE web parts is out-of-box web parts, you don't need to develop this.
   2.3. Create SharePoint add-in that will get data from web service.
   2.4. etc ....

May be I can suggest other options if you specify more precise requirements to implementation.

Just say how you see it in your imagination and I can suggest ways how to implement it.
Describe how it must be from user experience. Like 'I see page where I have three green buttons, color highlighted rows, auto-calculated field and so on and so on. I click button and get following result... ". Describe your expected user experience.

About trends - javascript rules now. In SharePoint Online you cannot create server code solutions hosted in SharePoint.
Best solution to use javascript to not change many things on migration to different version of SharePoint.